# Put picker selected dictionary value in another picker

Tags: c#, dictionary, xamarin

I'm having struggles with the following:
I have a Dictionary that gets filled by a webAPI.

```
    Dictionary<string, int> recipients = new Dictionary<string, int>();
```

And i have a picker

```
    pickerRecipients = new Picker
        {
        };
        foreach (string recipientName in recipients.Keys)
        {
            pickerRecipients.Items.Add(recipientName);
        }
```

What i want is that with the press of a button, the selected value to be put in a second Dictionary

```
    Dictionary<string, int> multiRecipients = new Dictionary<string, int>();
```

To add it i used

```
    multiRecipients.Add(KEY, VALUE);
```

But as far as i know, i could only acces the value, and not the key. I have no idea how to do that. I think the main problem is that i select it from a picker, and not directly from the dictionary.

Many thanks to anybody who can enlighten me (:

p.s. I use Xamarin

edit:
This is what i have now, but i also changed the int to a string, and the string to an int.

```
                if (pickerRecipients.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            string currentlySelected = pickerRecipients.Items[pickerRecipients.SelectedIndex];

            var SelectedValue = recipients[currentlySelected];
            multiRecipients.Add(currentlySelected, SelectedValue);
        }
```

Comment: you will have to get key using the value

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Yep, i tried. But i don't know exactly how i can get that.

Comment: do you have access to the recipients dictionry ?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad yup, i do

Comment: then see my posted answer, it should work for you then

Comment: based on what you posted, you already know the key (the selected Name from the picker), you just need to get the value.

Comment: Thanks guys! Too bad i can't select 2 answers, and Jason's code is a bit shorter, so to me it seems a little bit better. (Unless there's a good reason for it to be a bit longer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you already know the key to item, just use the [key] syntax to retrieve the value:

```
var SelectedValue = recipients[SelectedKey];
multiRecipients.Add(SelectedKey, SelectedValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use linq to get the key using the value from the dictionary, it would be like:

```
var key= recipients.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == selectedValue).Key;
multiRecipients.Add(key,selectedValue);
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! But what is the difference between yours and Jason's? As far as i know the result is the same.

Comment: my answer gets the Value using the Key; his answer gets the Key using the Value

Comment: the question text said the he know value but not key, did'nt noticed that in code it's the reverse of it :)

Comment: Okay, so what if i have 2 dictionary entries, lets say "Foo" "1" and "Foo" "2". In my case the int is always different, and the string has a (very small) potential to be the same. Then it's better to get the Key using the Value, right? Or doesnt it matter? @Jason @ Ehsan

Comment: `int` should be used as key and `string` as value IMO

Comment: Why is that? And I guess i would still be able to show the string in the picker?

Comment: by definition, the key of a Dictionary **must** be unique

Comment: Ah, okay. Didn't know that. Thanks! @Jason

Comment: I now changed it, but how do i get the key (int) now? Tried to change as much as possible, but how do i get that key? Because now i get the following error: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'int'. (Check question, i added some code)